# RXReplace Function Gives 'Invalid escape sequence: "\B".' #Error

Tags: regex, calculated-columns, spotfire, tibco

I'm using TIBCO Spotfire Analyst 7.8.0 HF-007 and trying to add a calculated column to create abbreviations for a string using a regular expression in the RXReplace function. However, I get an error stating "*Invalid escape sequence: "\B"*." which seems to not recognize the not word boundary.

The function **does** recognize the word boundary "\b". I've searched for an alternative to the not word boundary ("\B") expression, but have not found one.

The function call looks like: `RXReplace([Hospital_Name],"\B[a-zA-Z'-]+","","g")`

Is there an alternative to "\B" or a different approach to abbreviate a phrase (e.g., "MY HOSPITAL'S NAME" > "MHN")?

Comment: You should not  use `\B` here because its meaning is different when it is followed with a letter or `'` / `-`. What is the rule here? What context do you want the matches to occur in? Try `RXReplace([Hospital_Name], "\\b([a-zA-Z])\\S*", "$1", "g")`. Also, it seems you may just double the backslash, `RXReplace([Hospital_Name],"\\B[a-zA-Z'-]+","","g")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for responding. I'm not sure what you mean by context. I'm using the expression on hospital names (e.g., "Riverview Community Hospital") and want the expression to return the first letter of each word in the string (e.g., "RCH").

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I tried RXReplace([Hospital_Name],"\\B[a-zA-Z'-]+","","g") as you suggested and getting the letters with a space in between them ("R C H"). How should I modify the expression to get just the letters with no spaces?

Comment: `"\\B[a-zA-Z'-]+|\\s+"`

Comment: Or `"\\B[a-zA-Z'-]+|\\W+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
RXReplace([Hospital_Name], "\\B[a-zA-Z'-]+|\\W+", "", "g")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f1WTQW/2).

The backslashes should be doubled (to define one backslash `\\` must be written inside the string literal) and to remove any other non-word chars you need a `\W+` alternative in your regex.

See the [`RXReplace` documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.2/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm):

> Some characters, like for instance the backslash character `"\"`, need to be escaped to work when using calculated columns.

and

> The backslash needs to be escaped twice; once for the Spotfire string and once for the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you, that expression works! Could you explain why this needs double, instead of single, backslashes in the TIBCO function? The demo you provided only includes single gackslashes.

Comment: it comes down to the way strings are interpereted by the expression evaluator. if you have a TIBCO Support account you could raise a ticket to ask Spotfire Engineering for a more specific answer, but basically, "it's that way because that's the way it is" ;)

Comment: @Lucas In the online regex demo, I am using single backslashes because that is what is necessary to form a regex escape. A single literal backslash is used to escape some chars to form special regex sequences: `\s` matches a whitespace, `\b` is a word boundary. In your environment, ``\`` can be used to form *string escape sequences*, like `"\n"` is a newline. `"\B"` is thus an unknown string escape sequence, the string handling engine does not know how to parse this. To define a literal ``\`` in a string literal you need to use ``\\``.